# Different responses for requests with different mimetypes for same URL

Tags: api, http, rest, mime-types

Use case:
Let's say we have `www.example.org/statistics/` - with `text/json` it responses with JSON representation of raw data, with `text/html` it gives representation for human beings, with beauty, graphs, interactivity etc.

Is this good practice?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called [Content Negotiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) and it's great way to keep your URLs nice and tidy.